# Ansible change status to failed when unreachable

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

How to change the status of the ansible job? I want to set it to `failed` when the status is `UNREACHABLE`. I tried the following but still it shows as `UNREACHABLE`.

```
  - name: Set flag
    set_fact: flag = failed
    when: "'UNREACHABLE' in command_result.stderr"
```

Here is the ansible output:

```
TASK [Creating an empty file] **************************************************
task path: /tmp/bwrap_712_pjtf4f4e/awx_712_arau0my7/project/create-file.yml:7
<10.10.10.10> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<10.10.10.10> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ec2-user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/bwrap_712_pjtf4f4e/awx_712_arau0my7/cp/d88484738d 10.10.10.10 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ec2-user && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.10.10.10> (255, b'', b'ec2-user@10.10.10.10: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
fatal: [Ubuntu480]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ec2-user@10.10.10.10: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
Ubuntu480                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Instead, you can ignore it and let it [*fail*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html#ansible-builtin-fail-fail-with-custom-message) in the next task. For example

```yaml
    - command: echo Hello
      register: result
      ignore_unreachable: true
    - fail:
      when: result.unreachable
```

```yaml
TASK [command] **************************************************************
fatal: [host_99]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false 
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname host_99: Name or service not known'
  skip_reason: Host host_99 is unreachable
  unreachable: true

TASK [fail] *****************************************************************
fatal: [host_99]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: Failed as requested from task

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************
host_99 : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=1 failed=1 skipped=1 rescued=0 ignored=0
```